# Which system call is used for modifying file attributes on Linux?

Tags: linux

I asked this on Stack Overflow and they told me ask this question here. I've searched the net for pages mentioning file attributes and system calls, but none of them ever say which system call is responsible for changing the various attributes of a file or a folder. It's been implied that `fcntl()` is what I'm looking for, but it lacks arguments for the path and the new set of file attributes.

Comment: The person who refered you to this site was wrong. This question is at best borderline here: it is a programming question, and belongs on [so].

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27257370/what-is-the-linux-system-call-for-modifying-file-flags) the question that you're refering to? You asked a different question here: you can't use a system call if you're writing kernel code. Are you actually writing a kernel module, or do you want both pieces of information?

Comment: Yes, I'm writing a kernel module. A simply one, but a kernel module nonetheless.

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl_iflags.2.html Change file attributes from userspace

Answer (score 2):

The `chmod()` and `fchmod()` system calls change the Posix-style attributes, the user-group-other, read/write/execute permissions. It looks like the `ioctl()` system call can be used to set the "linux file system attributes" that the `chattr` and `lsattr` commands set and list.

Comment: Given that `chmod` the command only can modify the file's permission bits, I'm guessing that `fchmod()` is related to the file attributes, then. So, would this mean I'd have to intercept both `ioctl()` and `fchmod()` to, say, prevent the flags for immutable and append-only from being changed?

Comment: @Melab - `chmod()` and `fchmod()` are supposed to act identically, according to the man page. The only difference is `chmod()` takes a file name, `fchmod()` takes a file descriptor. "immutable" and "append-only" are a few of the linux file system attributes, so hooking `ioctl()` would be enough to keep those from being changed.

Comment: There isn't anyway a process could bypass `ioctl()` by using their own code, right? I think `dd` can.

Comment: @Melab any program with the right to access the disc directly can modify the bits if it knows how to find them.

Comment: byte level writing to filesystem while it's mounted has 99.9% possibility to break your filesystem.@Melab